# PDF embedded in HTML: use as hyperlink

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink

I have a PDF embedded in an HTML page (actually, it is an ASPX form). The PDF is shown in a small "embed" HTML element, making it look like a thumbnail. Now, I would like to use it as a hyperlink that would show the same PDF at full size. Is there a way to make the embedded PDF act as a hyperlink or am I asking for too much?

Here is the relevant HMTL:

```
<embed id="framePdfPreview" runat="server" width="200" height="255" />
```

And the server code that sets the PDF dynamically:

```
framePdfPreview.Attributes("src") = myPdfUrl & "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0"
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the code? Maybe if you wrap the pdf in a div you can add an action on click to that div and execute a link.

Comment: look at my answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Little experiment, I have never tried wrapping an `<embed>` with a `<div>` for this purpose, but theoretically it should work:

```
<div onclick="javascript: window.open('myPdfUrl ','Window Name')">
   <embed id="framePdfPreview" runat="server" width="200" height="255" />
</div>
```

This works, 100% tested for the division itself, I just hope that the browser will recognize your embeded pdf as part of the `<div>` if not you can also adjust the height and width of the division to the same of the pdf to make sure that the "link" covers the complete area of the pdf.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:255px" onclick="javascript: window.open('myPdfUrl ','Window Name')">
   <embed id="framePdfPreview" runat="server" width="200" height="255" />
</div>
```

We can try adding a division over the embeded PDF.
Get the exact position of the pdf and create a division of the same size with absolute position and the left and top values to mathc the pdf position, add `z-index:9999` and add to this new division the onclick property. Note that the pdf is outside the new div.

```
    <div style="width:200px; height:255px; z-index:99999; position:absolute; left:?px; top:?px" onclick="javascript: window.open('myPdfUrl ','Window Name')">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="pdf"><embed id="framePdfPreview" runat="server" width="200" height="255" /></div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work for me. The click event seems to be handled by the PDF element and does not bubble to the div container. If I make the div wider than the "embed" element, the event is triggered outside of the embedded PDF. So the event is setup correctly in the div but is not called when the mouse click is on the PDF.

Comment: I should add: thanks for the suggestion and for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I have another idea... look at my answer again.

Comment: Sorry for not following up with your suggestion. We have found a simpler solution. It involves converting the PDF to a JPEG image and showing the image in the page. Using it as a link is then straightforward and very reliable on all browsers.